# How do you exclude files that are larger than 500 megabytes from a bash?

Tags: if-statement, ffmpeg, find

So my goal is to convert all files that are in a certain directory with ffmpeg but not the ones that are smaller than let's say 500 megabytes?

What I made up so far is:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir converted
if [[ $(find -type f -size +500000) ]]; then
for i in *.mp4;
do ffmpeg -n -i "$i" -f mp4 -c:a aac -c:v libx265 -preset medium -crf 23 "converted/${i%}";done
fi
```

The script kind of works. ffmpeg starts running but it also converts the mp4s that are smaller than size +500000. I'm not good with scripting. I just started but I believe that I know where the mistake is. The if-clause tells ffmpeg to start running if there are certain files within the directory that are larger than x but it doesn't tell ffmpeg to exclude these files, right?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I did it.

```
    #!/bin/bash
    mkdir converted
    for var in *.mp4
    do
    FILESIZE=$(stat -c%s "$var")
    if [ "$FILESIZE" -lt 500000000 ]
    then
    echo "$var is smaller than 500MB";
    else
    ffmpeg -n -i "$var" -f mp4 -c:a aac -c:v libx265 -preset medium -crf 23 "converted/${var%}";
    fi
    done
```